# i have to send via CURL an input field (form in wordpress) to a remote php

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, exec

I have a form with an input textarea and I have to send what the user inserts to a php in a remote server.
the php in a remote server read what I send and simply echo what it reads. Obviously I have to show the response on my wordpress page.
my form is in a wordpress page and I have inserted my snippet shortcode. here my code, but it doesn't work...why? please

```html
<?php 

echo "<form action='http://xxx'";

echo " method='post'>";
    
    
        echo "<textarea rows='10' cols='100' name='testo_messaggio' placeholder='Ask me anything!'></textarea><br/>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='tasto_invia' value='Invia'/>";
    echo "</form>";

       echo "<div id='risposta'>";
    if (isset($_POST["tasto_invia"]))
    {
$post = [
    'QUERY' => 'testo_messaggio',

];

$ch = curl_init('http://xxx/sender.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

// execute!
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close the connection, release resources used
curl_close($ch);

// do anything you want with your response
//var_dump($response);
echo $response;}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

my code for sender.php is very simple

```
<?php
$value_1 = $_POST["QUERY"]; 
echo $value_1;
?>
```

Comment: What's not working?  What's the error message?  Could you maybe write `$value_1` to a file in `sender.php` to verify it's receiving information?

Comment: Don't use CURL in WordPress: the core team have [their own way of doing this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_request/), and it works much more reliably than CURL, and in more server environments.